# Using wrapper apex objects in Visualforce dynamic map, unexpected results

Tags: apex, visualforce

I'm trying to iterate over a map of custom apex objects in Visualforce and am unsure how to syntaxicly express it to work.

**Scenario that works: map of custom objects**

controller:

```
public Map<Id,cusObj__c> DummyRecordMap{get;set;}
```

VF

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!DummyRecordMap}" var="rId" >
         <apex:column >
            <apex:facet name="header">Record Name</apex:facet>
            <apex:outputfield value="{!DummyRecordMap[rId].Name}"/>
        </apex:column>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

**Scenario that does not work: map of apex wrapper objects - upd:actually this does work, the flaw was mine and unrelated.**

Now, in order to store some extra data per each record in memory I want to use a wrapper apex object as I believe is best practice in such cases. I have done this successfully with List in visualforce in the past, but trying to do this with a map it gives unexpected results. Am I doing something wrong ?

controller:

```
 public Map<Id,DummyWrapper> DummyWrapperMap{get;set;}

//wrapper class 
public class DummyWrapper{
    public boolean extraField {get;set;}
    public cusObj__c cusObj{get;set;}

    public DummyWrapper(cusObj__c cO){
        extraField = true;
        cusObj = cO;    
    }
}
```

Visualforce:

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!DummyWrapperMap}" var="rId" >
         <apex:column >
            <apex:facet name="header">Record Name</apex:facet>
               // --> this does not work like I would have expected <--
            <apex:outputfield value="{!DummyWrapperMap[rId].cusObj.Name}"/>
        </apex:column>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

This does not give errors but displays default values for the correct datatype of the field in the custom object that I try to display. The Name field displays an empty string, a date field the data of today and a decimal displays 0. These fields are unknown to the wrapperobject so the apex:outputfields I try to display them do show the correct datatype, but do not reflect the actual data.

Any ideas ?

(I know that as work around I can tunnel the custom object fields through wrapper object properties, but .. not what I'd prefer to do)

**Update: answer to comments**

```
public void buildDummyWrappers(){
    if(DummyRecordMap != null){
            Account ac = [select Id,name from account limit 1]; //TESTING
        DummyWrapperMap = new Map<id,Dummyrapper>();
        for(cusObj__c cO:DummyRecordMap.values()){
            dummyWrapperMap.put(c0.id,new DummyWrapper(co,ac));
        }
    }
}

    //wrapper class 
public class DummyWrapper{
    public boolean extraField {get;set;}
    public cusObj__c cusObj{get;set;}
            public Account Acc{get;set;} //TESTING

    public DummyWrapper(cusObj__c cO, Account ac){
        extraField = true;
        cusObj = cO;
                    Acc = ac;   
    }
}

<apex:repeat value="{!DummyWrapperMap}" var="rId">
         // this works, gives the records Ids (as it should)
         <apex:outputText value="{! rId}"/>
         //this also works fine
          <apex:outputText value="{! DummyWrapperMap[rId].extraField}"/>
         //this does not display anything
         <apex:outputText value="{! DummyWrapperMap[rId].cusObj.Name}"/><br />
         //This does work !
         <apex:outputText value="{! DummyWrapperMap[rId].Acc.Name}"/>
</apex:repeat>
```

**Final update:**  The problem was in fact in my code.  Got to use this.Field = field  instead of assuming the compiler will know the difference without this. Case insensitivity.

Comment: Not sure if it has something to do with outputField, does it work if you change it to outputText?

Comment: If manubkk's suggestion doesn't work, let me know what this produces for you: 
<apex:repeat value="{!DummyWrapperMap}" var="rId"> {!DummyWrapperMap[rId].extraField}<br/>{!DummyWrapperMap[rId].cusObj.Name}</apex:repeat>

Comment: Also how are you loading the map class?

Comment: @RichardTuttle I've updated the question

Comment: @Sdry - line 3 of the update you sent (buildDummyWrappers), was the "Dummyrapper" a typo, or actually that way in your code?

Comment: @RichardTuttle   Typo .. this is all abstracted simplified mock code. Unless someone can not reproduce this I have no reason to believe the problem is in my actual code (which I can not make public).

Comment: @Sdry understandable. I'm recreating now with your mock up to see if I see the same issue.  Replacing cusObj__c with account object.

Comment: @Sdry - it's in your code somewhere, works wonders on my end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in my comments it seems to be on your side somewhere.  Here is a proof of concept on my DE site:

http://ds-developer-edition.na8.force.com/ivr/test

I modified the custom object to be account for the sake of replicating the issue.  You can see the account names from a DE org showing through.  I put the code inside the page too so you can see exactly how it is functioning on my side.  Maybe that will spark an idea on your end.  Also of note, I'm using API 27.  I saw some problems on 15 (my test page is an old page).

Comment: I've tried to combine your replication with my code and added an account property to my wrapper .. which does work. Would you mind trying to replicate with a custom object too ? Going a bit crazy here.

Comment: Sure, give me a few.  We really need a JSFiddle type of application for Apex/VF.  Would make quick things like this so much easier.

Comment: Nevermind. I figured it out.

Comment: Yep works still.  Tested using Milestone__c from the milestones appexchange app.  What was the issue?

Comment: Stupidity Mostly.  (My actual code had a property with the same name as the constructor parameter, and I didn't use this. when assigning the param val to the property. )  @all plz give this guy some Rep.

Comment: Ahh, sometimes the biggest pains are the simplest fixes.